# Data transfer between non-matching structured Mysql Database

Tags: mysql, data-migration

How to transfer data from `db1.tab1` to `db2.tab2` ?

Here `db2.tab2` have different field name from db1.tab1.
I tried with mysql work bench but it is not giving 100% result.

I'm using Xampp and mysql 5.6.22

Thanks

Comment: @PrasadKhode yes. but both having fields with different name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below query.

```
INSERT INTO db2.`tab2` ( `id`, `user_name`, `password`, `is_active` ) SELECT `user_id`, `name`, `pass`, `active` FROM db1.`tab1`;
```

As you can see the **column name are different** in both tables.

So you have to mention on which column of `table2`, you want to insert which column data from `table1`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any tool or sql mechanism to do this? Because I have more than 10gb of data. The above query will take more time to complete.

Comment: I don't know any tool which can do the same faster. There are various ETL tools like Talend where you can map the fields of one database to other database database fields and then run it.

Comment: If you are going for talend, then you have to download it by below link. http://www.talend.com/download/talend-open-studio?qt-product_tos_download=3#qt-product_tos_download

Answer (score 1):

You have to add fields only you want to the following mysql query:

```
INSERT INTO table_name1(fields_you_want)
SELECT fields_you_want FROM table_name2
```

Ex:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT column_1, column_2, column_3
FROM table1
```